# Getting wrong sender in event handler for checkboxes

Tags: asp.net

I have dynamically generated checkboxes and having EventHandler which takes care about check change of any of the checkbox. The issue is that if i uncheck any of the checkbox, it gets all other checkbox as sender and checkchange is called according to number of checkboxes number of times. If there are 3 checkboxes and 1 is unchecked than checkchange event handler is called 2 times. I dont understand what is happening.

```
    CheckBox chkbox;
        panelDynamicCheckbox.Controls.Clear();
        foreach(string product in products)
        {
            chkbox = new CheckBox();
            chkbox.ID = product;
            chkbox.Text = product;
            chkbox.AutoPostBack = true;                
            chkbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckChanged);
            panelDynamicCheckbox.Controls.Add(chkbox);
       }


     protected void CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
     }
```

Comment: If I cnt create checkbox dynamically, I have to add 22 checkbox statistically and make them visible/invisible. So please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the code to add the dynamic checkbox and especially the event handler specification is done in the **`OnInit`** method in the page life-cycle. If you don't do this, these sort of unpredictable state behavior can be seen.

Comment: I called a method from OnInit which dynamically generates checkboxes. But I have to again call that method from Page_Load as while postback the dynamically generated checkboxes get removed.